Problem of deleting the data from a Room Database (Android Studio Java)
I have 7 class: MainActivity class (the place where Recycler View are shown), AddNote class, UpdateNote class, NoteDao class, NoteDatabase class (i use the singleton database structure), NoteAdapter class and Note class (model)
Below is the output of my current codes:
1st: Initially, there is no Note item in the Recycler View, so i click the "ADD" button to add some notes, Eg: 1 and 2.
FIRST PIC
2nd: When i click "recycle bin" button, it will make the delete button appear for each item, so i can delete the item.
SECOND PIC
3rd: So i click delete, and it seems CORRECT for the Recycler View:
THIRD PIC
4th: So when i want to add new note,Eg: 3, 4, and 5, It also seems CORRECT.
FOURTH PIC
FIFTH PIC
5TH: THE PROBLEM LIES AT HERE: When i want to view each note, it appear the detail of the note before!
Eg: when i click on the 3, it give me 1
click 4, give me 2
click 5, give me 3... etc
I look up on this for whole 2 days using CHATGPT, CLAUDEAI, YOUTUBE, STACKOVERFLOW, GOOGLE still, didn't now HOW TO SOLVE this problem... :( Im feeling soooo tired.
IMO: i feel like this is due to i have wrongly written the code of deleting the item from the database. PROBLEM is now the ITEM is successfully deleted from the RecyclerView but failed to delete from the Room Database...
THIS IS MY NoteAdapter class:
package com.example.tostudylistv2.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.tostudylistv2.Activities.MainActivity;
import com.example.tostudylistv2.Activities.UpdateNote;
import com.example.tostudylistv2.Database.NoteDatabase;
import com.example.tostudylistv2.Note;
import com.example.tostudylistv2.R;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class NoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.ViewHolder>{
        private Context context;
        private List<Note> noteList;
        private boolean showDoDel = false;
    
    public NoteAdapter(Context context, List<Note> noteList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.noteList = noteList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.note,parent,false); // to let all UI/ View in the XML layout to be usable
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtNote.setText(noteList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"WORK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateNote.class);
                i.putExtra("position",position);
                context.startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        if (showDoDel) {
            holder.btnDoDel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.btnDoDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    delNoteInBackground(noteList.get(position));
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            holder.btnDoDel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }



    }
    public void delNoteInBackground(Note note) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                NoteDatabase.getInstance(context).getNoteDao().deleteNote(note);

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted from the database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (!noteList.isEmpty()) {
                            noteList.remove(note);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Nothing to delete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return noteList.size();
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { //initialize all the UI element/ view of the item here

        private TextView txtNote;
        private ImageView btnDoDel;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtNote = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNote);
            btnDoDel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDoDel);
        }
    }

    public void setNoteList(List<Note> noteList) {
        this.noteList = noteList;
    }
    public void setShowDoDel(boolean showDoDel) {
        this.showDoDel = showDoDel;
    }

}

This is my MainActivity class:
package com.example.tostudylistv2.Activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.tostudylistv2.Database.NoteDatabase;
import com.example.tostudylistv2.Note;
import com.example.tostudylistv2.RecyclerView.NoteAdapter;
import com.example.tostudylistv2.R;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView noteRecView;
    private List<Note> noteList = new ArrayList<>();
    private FloatingActionButton btnAdd, btnDel, btnBack;
    private ImageView btnDoDel;
    private EditText input;
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;
    private NoteAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        noteRecView = findViewById(R.id.noteRecView);

        init();
        initListener();

        initActivityLauncher();

        adapter = new NoteAdapter(this, noteList);
        noteRecView.setAdapter(adapter);

        LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        noteRecView.setLayoutManager(lm);

        getNoteInBackground();

    }

    public void init() {
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnDel = findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
        btnBack = findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        btnDoDel = findViewById(R.id.btnDoDel);
        input = findViewById(R.id.input);
    }

    public void initListener() {
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNote.class);
                activityResultLauncher.launch(i);
            }
        });

        btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.setShowDoDel(true);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //***important, to refresh the RecView and display the result!!!
                btnDel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                btnBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                adapter.setShowDoDel(false);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                btnDel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
    }


    public void addNoteInBackground(Note note) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NoteDatabase.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getNoteDao().addNote(note);

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Added to the database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        noteList.add(note);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void getNoteInBackground() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                noteList = NoteDatabase.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getNoteDao().getAllNote();

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.setNoteList(noteList);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }


    public void initActivityLauncher() {
        activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult activityResult) {
                        int result = activityResult.getResultCode();
                        Intent data = activityResult.getData();

                        if (result == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                            String newTitle = data.getStringExtra("tempTitle");
                            if (newTitle != null && !newTitle.isEmpty()) {
                                Note newNote = new Note(newTitle);
                                addNoteInBackground(newNote);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Operation canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}

It should delete the Item from the RecyclerView and Room Database successfully.
